# How to add custom validation which calls an API in vuetify forms?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to add custom validation to a form to test for duplicate entry.
How can I do it using only vuetify validation. I want to show a inline error message if the user input is duplicate.

Comment: Can you paste the piece of code or example, that would really help to resolve your issue..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can validate the name from customer input with api call and throw error to user, if the name already exist or duplicate name found

You can use rules property in vuetify text fields, it takes an array of functions and expect true(validation true, in your case name not exists) or string(if valdation false, name exists in db)

Here is the working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/eYYdPzQ?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-form
        ref="form"
        v-model="valid"
      >
        <v-text-field
          v-model="name"
          :counter="10"
          :rules="[checkDuplicate, rules.required]"
          label="Name"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-btn @click="submitbtn">submit</v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    valid:true,
    name: '',
    rules: {
      required: v => !!v || 'this field is required',
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    checkDuplicate(val) {
      // write your api call and return the below statement if it already exist
      if (val == 'test') {
        return `Name "${val}" already exist`;
       } else {
         return true;
       }

    },
    submitbtn() {
      this.$refs.form.validate();
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Let's say I want to do another validation like required and want this duplicate validation to appear on a button click. How can I do it?

Comment: Add another method named required required then add it to , :rules array

Comment: Thanks chans is there a way to avoid validating as the user types. I want the validation to happen only when the user press submit

Comment: Remove from rules and write a methods to validate all fields, explicitly. Do accept and upvote this answer

Comment: while using this, you will get sonar error for returning inconsistently,
where error message is STRING, else boolean,
is there any other solution

Comment: @SathishSundar you can add more logic to this code to have error response handling, write conditions to return boolean true if success and error message in string format, because this is the convention they are following in Vuetify, we are taking that advantage and handling in our code

Comment: @chans can you share me the code snippet regarding the above which i mentioned.
so that it will be helpful to understand.